# Inserting document compiled from LaTex code inside a .tex file

Tags: beamer, packages, environments

Is there a way to insert a document within a document? The inserted code is fully .tex compliant and could be compiled as a document on its own.

I envision an article document, where inside the document, I show multiple beamer documents. The purpose of this is to demonstrate various beamer features and how they affect the final beamer presentation.

I would guess the code would look something like this,

```
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{latexinsert} % hypothetical package

\begin{document}

\begin[frame = single]{insert_environment} % hypothetical environment name
%frame around the inserted document compiled from LaTeX code
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}

\end{insert_environment}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Maybe look at the source code for the beamer manual for an implementation?

Comment: Look at the package `docmute`.   It will allow you to have individually compilable tex documents which can be either `input`ed or `included`ed into your main document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [`standalone`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/standalone) bundle. Note that I use the word 'bundle' because `standalone` represents both a `documentclass` and a `package`!

Let's say that you have a file `framefile.tex` that has the following code

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}

\begin{document}

Hello, world!
\[
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
\end{document}
```

This file can be compiled on its own. Note that this file uses `standalone` as `documentclass`.

Now let's create your `mainfile.tex` which can `input` your `framefile.tex`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \input{framefile}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that this file uses `standalone` as a `package`.