# Recommended workflow for fixing several nasty frames in beamer?

Tags: beamer, workflow

I have a pretty long presentation: a course comprising a couple of hundreds frames. Occasionally, I go over the presentation, notice a few corrections in distinct frames.

Fixing these requires a number of iterations to find the most pleasing placement of objects, texts, and figures. Needless to say, running LaTeX on the entire presentation is time consuming.

Instead, I mark the slides with `label=current` and use `includeonlyframes{current}` which renders only the `current` slides. However, I get the annoying

```
 LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

Is there a more civilized way of managing the workflow. It seems too cumbersome to mark each slide with a different label, and then enumerate the labels in the `includeonlyframes` command.

Comment: For exactly this purpose I use the `comment` package to comment out parts I do not want to compile. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/commenting-out-large-sections/62096#62096

Comment: I usually prepare a few frames in a separate file that has only the preamble in common with the main one; cross references are not a problem during the preparation of the presentation. When they're ready, I transfer them to the main file; the same idea can be used for fixing some of the already finished ones.

Comment: It is only a warning. I just ignore it: I know exactly what is causing the warning and I know that it does not matter at this point in my workflow. When I have things as I like, I remove the labels, comment the includeonlyframes and reprocess. Only at this point do I pay attention to warnings of this kind. Civilisation is overrated!

Comment: you could also look at the `standalone` bundle- a demonstration for `beamer` is given in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73829/inserting-document-compiled-from-latex-code-inside-a-tex-file for example

Comment: Use  `%\input{frame1}`, `%\input{frame2}`, ...  and uncomment only those you are workin on. This way you have many files but you (*a*) can concentrate on the working frame (*b*) cannot damage the code of another frame accidentally (*c*) can reuse easily the frame in another presentations and (*d*) exclude-include according to the available time for your disssertation or the type of audience.

Comment: Too obvious, but if you are working in the 4th of 200 frames, the easiest  is just place a temporal `\end{document}` after the 4th frame (equally obvious, this is of little help when you are working in the 195th frame).

Comment: I use same approach as @egreg. Use a separate file with same preamble. I also use a `\input` to share the same preamble on both files. So my minimum framework for long beamer presentation is the `main.tex`, `temp.tex` and `preamble.tex`.

Comment: @egreg Your comment has the most upvotes, wanna write up an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually prepare a few frames in a separate file that has only the preamble in common with the main one.

Missing labels for cross references are not a problem during the preparation of the presentation: they might cause some slight difference in the final printout, but the chances are very small. Actually I almost never use cross references in presentation, but only hyperlinks: I don't find something like “see [1]” or “see slide 24” useful for the attendance.

When the group of slides is ready, I transfer them to the main file; the same idea can be used for fixing some of the already finished ones.

In this way, compilation of the whole presentation is almost never needed except in the final production stages.

One could even avoid copying the preamble by having it in a third file as in the scheme below. In the final stage it may be more convenient to transfer the contents of `preamble.tex` into the main file so it's self-contained (except for graphics).

### Main file

```
\documentclass[<options>]{beamer}

\input{preamble}

\begin{document}

<already prepared slides>

\end{document}
```

### Galley file

```
\documentclass[<options>]{beamer}

\input{preamble}

\begin{document}

<slides in preparation>

\end{document}
```

### `preamble.tex` file (scheme)

```
\usebeamertheme{Whatever}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

...<whatever needed in the preamble>...
```